# Computer script for auto-reboot on network loss

Tags: performance, batch-file, cmd

I am working with a IP Camera network and need a script to run on each individual PC that will perform an auto-reboot when network loss happens.  I would like to be able to have the PC ping the servers IP every 5 minutes and upon loss of connectivity the PC will reboot.  Each PC has a Camera viewer but periodically looses network connection with the NVR.  I found almost the same issue/solution here: http://www.cam-it.org/index.php?topic=2786.0

However the script provided didn't work for me.  Below is the script I found and tried but didn't function the way I needed.

```
@Echo off
REM Put REM in front of Echo off to view the file output
REM ---------------------------------------------------------
REM WATCHDOG.CMD
REM     Restarts PC after 3 unsuccessful attempts to PING the
REM     POE switch
REM --------------------------------------------------------

SET COUNT=C:\Temp\WATCHDOG.txt
SET POESWITCH=192.168.1.253
SET ERRFLG=0

IF EXIST "%COUNT%" (
SET /P ERRFLG= <%COUNT%
)

IF %ERRFLG% GTR 2 (
Echo Restarting PC in 60 seconds.  Run SHUTDOWN -a to abort.
DEL %COUNT%
SHUTDOWN -r -t 60 -f
GOTO :EOF
)

PING -n 1 %POESWITCH%|findstr /I /C:"timed out" /C:"unreachable" /C:"general failure"
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 Goto Done

SET /a ERRFLG +=1
ECHO %ERRFLG% > %COUNT%

:Done
```

(http://www.cam-it.org/index.php?topic=2786.0)

---

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Jordan

Comment: so what's the exact error?

Comment: i disconnect the computer in question from the network and after 3 attempts the computer does not reboot.

Comment: does script write anything to output?

Comment: do PING, SHUTDOWN commands and WATCHDOG.TXT exist?

Answer (score 0):

Add the reboot command and it should work for you to test a URL/IP address every 300 seconds

```
@echo off
set ip=www.google.com
:loop
  ping -n 2 %ip% |find "TTL=" >nul || echo reboot command here
  ping -n 300 localhost >nul
goto :loop
```